# Change home page file name in vuepress

Tags: vuejs2, vuepress

By default project root README.md with some YML configuration is used as a home page in Vuepress. Is there any way to use some other file for the same?

I want to use README.md for some other purpose, like creating project build and deployment notes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an inquiry in the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress) version 1.0.2, I didn't know this extension of vue, so it was a good exercise.

I looked at all occurrences of readme, case insensitive, and it turns out that what you want is **not configurable**, as `readme` is hardcoded in several files.

I changed several occurrences of `readme` in the source code, and managed to change the landing page to `test.md`.

Here are the files you need to change in the source code:

- vuepress/packages/@vuepress/shared-utils/src/isIndexFile.ts
- vuepress/packages/@vuepress/markdown/lib/link.js
- vuepress/packages/@vuepress/core/lib/node/Page.js
- vuepress/packages/@vuepress/markdown-loader/index.js

There, in the relevant strings, you have to replace `readme` (or `README`, depending) with your desired file name.

### Another solution:

Nest your vuepress inside a folder looking like:

```
- src/
   |
   -- README.md
   -- vuepress/
        | 
        -- README.md
```

Comment: Thanks @Damien for your time & effort. Will try to use the 2nd approach you shared. Meanwhile you can contribute the fix to make it configurable (if you wish), otherwise I will work on the same.